# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull renderingMode]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbar

I am using `UITableview` with `UITabbar` navigation . In some `UITableView` I am getting this crash issue .

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull renderingMode]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fc6cf9a8'

this issue only occurs after upgrade from ios 12 to iOS 13.

Comment: so issue in converting from ios 12 to ios 13 for viewController(contains tableview) from storyboards (one view controller connected with storyboard nib.) When I push to that view it gives that error . but same code working fine in ios 12.

Comment: Sure but an `unrecognized selector` means you are assuming an object is a certain type when in fact it's another type, and in the case of `UITableView` implies the data source contains invalid data.

Comment: Anyway this question cannot be answered as their isn't enough information.